# Html5 canvas помощь в реализации стрелочки

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, canvas

Имеется код:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// general settings
var middleX = canvas.width / 2;
var middleY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = canvas.width / 2 - canvas.width / 10;
var startAngleIndex = 0.7;
var endAngleIndex = 2.3;


// Arrow settings
var arrowValueIndex = 1.5;
var arrowColor = "#d01617";
var arrowWidth = canvas.width / 20;


var DrawArrow = function() {
  var arrowAngle = arrowValueIndex * Math.PI;
  var toX = middleX + (radius) * Math.cos(arrowAngle);
  var toY = middleY + (radius) * Math.sin(arrowAngle);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(middleX, middleY);
  ctx.lineTo(toX, toY);
  ctx.strokeStyle = arrowColor;
  ctx.lineWidth = arrowWidth;
  ctx.stroke();

};
DrawArrow();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

[Этот же код на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1jdqvum0/)

нужно сделать вот так : [image: стрелочка]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самым простым для вас вариантом будет взять готовую стрелочку и уже нарисовать ее. Приведу пример рисования стрелочки из SVG элемента.
Просто скопируем PATH стрелки и передадим его в конструктор Path2D

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let arrow = new Path2D("M10.273,5.009c0.444-0.444,1.143-0.444,1.587,0c0.429,0.429,0.429,1.143,0,1.571l-8.047,8.047h26.554  c0.619,0,1.127,0.492,1.127,1.111c0,0.619-0.508,1.127-1.127,1.127H3.813l8.047,8.032c0.429,0.444,0.429,1.159,0,1.587  c-0.444,0.444-1.143,0.444-1.587,0l-9.952-9.952c-0.429-0.429-0.429-1.143,0-1.571L10.273,5.009z");

ctx.fillStyle = '#ffcc00';
ctx.fill(arrow);
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
```